# How can I start new Laravel project with breeze?

Tags: laravel

This is my laravel new project composer.json file content.

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.1|^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.29",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.3",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5.8|^9.3.3"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.4.3"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
}
```

I downloaded new laravel framework via running command successfully.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel project
```

And I wanna use starter-kits breeze.

So, I run

```
composer require laravel/breeze --dev
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires illuminate/filesystem ^8.45, found illuminate/filesystem[v8.45.0, v8.45.1, 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
```

I tried to run `composer update` and `composer require illuminate/filesystem`.
`composer update` is working well. But the problem is not solved.
`composer require illuminate/filesystem` is getting same error.
Please help me.

Comment: Please share your `composer.json` file content

Comment: Shared composer.json file content. Thank you.

Comment: That fact that https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/starter-kits is a 404 error (where https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits is not) should indicate that this feature is not available for your current version of Laravel 7.x. Can you use Laravel 8.x instead?

Comment: I have one question for that. I used default command. I did not set laravel version when install laravel project. Why is it downloading not latest version?

Comment: Do not create the project from composer, use curl instead [Installation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-macos). Or clone the [github repo](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) and run composer install.

Comment: Ah, I got it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you have `laravel version 7` and laravel 7 doesn't support laravel-breeze
so you have to update your `laravel version to 8` then you can use it.

> You can follow these setps ,that will help you to work with laravel 8, work with Laravel Breeze or Laravel Jetstream

**Updating the Installer**

If you already have `laravel/installer` required globally on your local machine, you can update the latest version of `laravel/installer` with any of the following approaches:

1. Update to `^4.0` via `composer require`
2. Uninstall and re-install the package via Composer

**Composer Require**

The simplest way to update to the next major version of the installer is via `composer require` to globally require it:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer:^4.0"
```

As long as you don’t have dependency conflicts, you should now have the latest `4.x` version of the installer. I’d recommend updating once a week (at least at first) to get merged updates/bug fixes surrounding the Laravel 8 launch.
Once you’ve required the `4.x` version, you can verify the installation within the Laravel CLI:

```
laravel --version
Laravel Installer 4.0.3
```

**Uninstall and Re-install**

If you run into issues updating via `composer requir`e, you can always uninstall and re-install via the command line. which is using `composer` to globally remove the old version and re-install `laravel/installer`

```
composer global remove laravel/installer 
composer global require laravel/installer
```

**Verifying the Update**

As mentioned above—regardless of which approach you use to update the installer—ensure you have the correct version:

```
laravel --version
Laravel Installer 4.2.5
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
As I ased to @porloscerros Ψ,
I have one question for that. I used default command. I did not set laravel version when install laravel project. Why is it downloading not latest version?

Comment: because you have installed laravel 7 but now you need to update it the new laravel version

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I got the solution for my problem from  @porloscerros-Ψ.